# An error occurred while loading the data of the collection file in MongoDB using the toArray() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, find, toarray

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var db;

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on 8080');
});


app.get('/', function (req, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/write', function (req, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/write.html');
});


app.get('/list', function (req,response) {
    db.collection('post').find().toArray(function(err, results){
        console.log(results);
    });
    response.render('list.ejs');
});
```

i want to call my data from collection of mongodb database.

but i have a Typeerror "collection" undefined!

please help me!

[image]
i tried googling and i want to show my data to browser!

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more details around the error. Things like the full error and which line causes it would help. Thanks

Comment: First, you will need to connect to the database server using the `MongoClient.connect(...)` method`. Then, read from the database, e.g., `MongoClient.db('db_name).collection('colln_name).find(...''`. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you very much ! after i connected mongodb url then it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have imported the module but you haven't configured the database.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017), {native_parser: true});
var db = mongoclient.db("COLLECTION_NAME");
```

For more information check here
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: after i connect mongodb url then it works! Thanks!